# Return multiple values in a single oracle sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is a query that is in java

```
SELECT achieve_STATUS_CD
FROM achievemnt
WHERE env_id = '?' AND ROWNUM = 1 
ORDER BY achive_status_dt
```

which needs to return value 'Y' based from another two tables enrollment, provision with below conditions

1. enrollment.achieve_intent = '2'
2. enrollment.BEGIN_DT >=
                      TO_DATE (
                         05/01/2011,
                         'MM/DD/YYYY')
   3.provision.RELEASE_DT <= SYSDATE

for the rest all conditions it should return the values from original query (SELECT achieve_STATUS_CD FROM achievemnt WHERE env_id = '?' AND ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY achive_status_dt)

achievemnt is child table of enrollment

How can i write this logic ?

I have written the below query but it has env_id at 2 places but we cant change that in our java for now so i need to write in a single query which accepts env_id only at once

```
WITH TMP
     AS (SELECT 'Y' AS achieve_STATUS_CD, env_id
           FROM enrollment r, provision a
          WHERE     r.prov_id = a.prov_id
                AND r.achieve_intent = '2'
                AND a.BEGIN_DT >=
                       TO_DATE (
                          05/01/2011,
                          'MM/DD/YYYY')
                AND a.RELEASE_DT <= SYSDATE AND R.env_ID = '?')
SELECT NVL (F.achieve_STATUS_CD,TMP.achieve_STATUS_CD)
FROM TMP FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT achieve_STATUS_CD
      FROM achievemnt
      WHERE env_id = '?' AND
            ROWNUM = 1
      ORDER BY achive_status_dt
     ) F
     ON TMP.env_ID = F.env_ID;
```

Comment: First, I suspect your initial query is incorrect.  The `rownum = 1` predicate will be applied before the `order by` so you're picking whichever row is arbitrarily encountered first and sorting that one row.  It seems likely that you want the value from the row with the first `achive_status_dt` instead.  I'm not sure that I understand the rest of your question.  If you just want the logic of the last query with a single bind variable, simply create another CTE that selects the bind value from dual and reference that CTE as many times as you'd like in the rest of your query.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i use CTE that selects the bind value from dual and i can reference

Comment: This is in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Your initial query is highly likely to be incorrect.  The `rownum = 1` predicate in this query is applied before the `ORDER BY` so you're asking for an arbitrary row where the `env_id` is whatever bind value and then sorting the resulting single row.  Sorting a single row is obviously pointless.

```
SELECT achieve_STATUS_CD
  FROM achievemnt
 WHERE env_id = '?' 
   AND ROWNUM = 1 
 ORDER BY achive_status_dt
```

If you want to sort multiple rows and to pick the row with the first `achive_status_dt`, you'd want something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT achieve_STATUS_CD
          FROM achievemnt
         WHERE env_id = '?' 
         ORDER BY achive_status_dt) a
 WHERE a.ROWNUM = 1
```

If your actual question, though, is that the second query does what you want (which seems unlikely given the issue I just mentioned) but you want to do it with a single bind variable, you can simply add another CTE that selects the bind variable from `dual` and then reference that CTE wherever you'd like

```
WITH env
     AS (SELECT '?' env_id from dual)
    ,TMP
     AS (SELECT 'Y' AS achieve_STATUS_CD, env_id
           FROM enrollment r, provision a, env
          WHERE     r.prov_id = a.prov_id
                AND r.achieve_intent = '2'
                AND a.BEGIN_DT >=
                       TO_DATE (
                          05/01/2011,
                          'MM/DD/YYYY')
                AND a.RELEASE_DT <= SYSDATE 
                AND R.env_ID = env.env_ID)
SELECT NVL (F.achieve_STATUS_CD,TMP.achieve_STATUS_CD)
FROM TMP FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT achieve_STATUS_CD
      FROM achievemnt
           join env
             on achievement.env_id = env.env_id
      WHERE ROWNUM = 1
      ORDER BY achive_status_dt
     ) F
     ON TMP.env_ID = F.env_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, it worked and i learned how to use the bind variable only once using the above method

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that :

1- the question of rownum is correct  (i agree with Justin)

2- the achievemnt table is always populated

You can release the condition

> AND R.env_ID = '?'

on the TMP subquery. 
In this case, it should be enough that the query is a LEFT outer join based on env_id.

So the full query should become like this (i don't have an sql console to test it)

```
WITH TMP
 AS (SELECT 'Y' AS achieve_STATUS_CD, env_id
       FROM enrollment r, provision a
      WHERE     r.prov_id = a.prov_id
            AND r.achieve_intent = '2'
            AND a.BEGIN_DT >=
                   TO_DATE (
                      05/01/2011,
                      'MM/DD/YYYY')
            AND a.RELEASE_DT <= SYSDATE ),
F 
AS (SELECT TMP.achieve_STATUS_CD
  FROM achievemnt
  WHERE env_id = '?' AND
        ROWNUM = 1
  ORDER BY achive_status_dt)
SELECT NVL (TMP.achieve_STATUS_CD, F.achieve_STATUS_CD)
FROM F LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP
 ON  F.env_ID=TMP.env_ID;
```

Note that i inverted the NVL fields: if TMP.achieve_STATUS_CD is not null, i.e. if a row exists, that value, which is always Y, should be taken, otherwise the value from achievemnt.

If the assuntion 2 is not true, you can invert the 2 subqueries in the outer join.

If you need the record from achievemnt with the oldest date, F may become something like this

```
SELECT TMP.achieve_STATUS_CD, achive_status_dt, env_id, min(achive_status_dt)  OVER(partition by end_id) min_date
  FROM achievemnt
  WHERE env_id = '?' AND
        achive_status_dt=min_date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand your question (and I may be completely wrong): If at least one enrollment/provision pair that matches your criteria exists for an env_id show 'Y', otherwise show the first achievement status for it.

```
select 
  case when exists
  (
    select *
    from enrollment e
    join provision p on p.prov_id = e.prov_id
    where e.achieve_intent = '2'
    and p.begin_dt >= date '2011-05-01'
    and p.release_dt <= sysdate 
    and e.env_id = :env_id
  ) then 'Y'
  else
  (
    select max(achieve_status_cd) keep (dense_rank first order by achive_status_dt)
    from achievement
    where env_id = :env_id
  ) as status
from dual;
```

If you want to have :env_id only once in your query, change it slightly to:

```
select 
  case when exists
  (
    select ...
    and e.env_id = main.env_id
  ) then 'Y'
  else
  (
    select ...
    where env_id = main.env_id
  ) as status
from (select :env_id as env_id from dual) main;
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, for providing the alternate solution it worked too in my case.